# ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1

Tags: python, python-2.7, m2crypto

I want to build M2Crypto for Windows x64 to be used in python 2.7 in Windows x64.
I downloaded the library package named: "M2CryptoWin64-master" from: https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto

Then, I followed these steps from [enter link description here](https://github.com/dsoprea/M2CryptoWindows):

> In setup.py:
>
> replace self.openssl = 'C:\pkg' by self.openssl =
>   'C:\grr-build\openssl' replace name = 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' , by name
>   = '__m2crypto' Build:
>
> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\grr-build\swigwin-2.0.9 C:\Python27\python.exe
>   setup.py build C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install To get M2Crypto
>   to work for PyInstaller:
>
> Rename C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg
>   to C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg.zip
>   extract M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg.zip into
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ without a
>   M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg sub directory remove
>   M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg.zip

When I test the library by going to Python.exe and type:

```
>>> import M2Crypto
```

I get this message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\m2crypto-0.22.3-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\M2Cryp
>   to__init__.py", line 22, in 
>       import __m2crypto ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.

Can you please help me figure out how to solve the issue?

**EDIT:**
I also did the following to get M2Crypto to work for PyInstaller:

> Rename C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg to 
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg.zip
>   extract M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg.zip into
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ without a
>   M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg sub directory remove
>   M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win32.egg.zip

Comment: Copy related DLL to Python DLL source dir.

Comment: @SDilmac could plz clarify more? what are the related DLL? where is the Python DLL source dir? I am a beginner. I also added edit to the post. I am following a guide. I need clear steps plz.

Comment: you're probably using 32 bit python... This is a common error that you could have googled. You need either a 32 bit library, or a 64 bit version of python.

Comment: I am using python 64-bit. I tested this also to make sure. This is how I tested python version: `import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)` and the result was: `('7fffffffffffffff', True)`.